# How to import vcf file to show in my website

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

![enter image description here][1]

it like a  when click name   then  show  Picture ,Name ,Email, phone number
on the right side     (in my contact that a example not a information from vcf file

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I can't show my picture sorry sir .  It like a import vcf file to show information
I dont know  how to import vcf file sir